# Save multi value in multi value field programmatically

Tags: entities, media

**apologize every one , my code was correct , I had a mistake in content type .2 similar content type with 2 similar image field :P**

**but I let it and don't delete this because maybe be useful in futures**

I want to save multi image in multi image field programmatically(I set number of value to 5)

Part of my code

```
        $node = new stdClass(); // Create a new node object
        $node->type = "prodcut_gift_display"; // Or page, or whatever content type you like
        $node->uid = $user->uid;
        $uri = file_build_uri($geturipath);
        $file = new stdClass;
        $file->uid = $user->uid;
        $file->filename = basename($uri);
        $file->uri = $uri;
        $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($uri);
        $file->filesize = filesize($mainimg_url);
        $file->status = 1;
        file_save($file);
        $node->field_gift_image['und'][0] =(array) $file;
        /***************************************/
        foreach ($upimg_uri_path as $inx=>$upimgtemp){
        unset($file);
        $uri = file_build_uri($upimgtemp);
        $file = new stdClass;
        $file->uid = $user->uid;
        $file->filename = basename($uri);
        $file->uri = $uri;
        $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($uri);
//        $file->filesize = filesize($mainimg_url);
        $file->status = 1;
        file_save($file);
        $node->field_gift_image['und'][$inx+1]=(array) $file;
        }

        /***************************************/
```

Then I try to get `drupal_json_output` , it seems node and image field with 2 value is  ok but only one value saved in field.**where is the problem?**(I check and sure that my image field is set multi and can get 5 value )

**update**
Also I try

```
$uri = file_build_uri($geturipath);

        $imgs_paths[]=file_create_url($uri);
        /***************************************/
        foreach ($upimg_uri_path as $inx=>$upimgtemp){
        unset($file);
        $uri = file_build_uri($upimgtemp);
        $imgs_paths[]=file_create_url($uri);
        }

   foreach ($imgs_paths as $i=>$img) {
    $file_info = system_retrieve_file($img, 'public://pictures/', TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE); //storing image inside picture folder
    if ($file_info->fid) {//if fid exist then image is saved from URL.
      $node->field_gift_image['und'][$i]['fid'] = $file_info->fid; //assign image
    }
  }
        /***************************************/
        $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id'] = $my_prodcut->product_id;
        $node->title = arg(1) . '-' . rand(1, 999999);
        $node->language = 'fa';
        $node = node_submit($node);
        node_save($node);
```

Also my field settings 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this "multi"? Do you mean you're using [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget)?

Comment: a image field that can save multi value !!!

Comment: You can try without und if your site is not multilingual. But I see, it should work. make node_save($node); $node = node_load($node->nid); dpm($node) . I do not see if it is saved by wrong way.

Comment: apologize every one , my code was correct , I had a mistake in content type .2 similar content type with 2 similar image field :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to create a new article content type with multiple images. Assuming that you have the path of the images. In Drupal 7 you can use the below code

```
  $node = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object
  $node->type = "article"; // Or any other content type you want
  $node->title = "Article title";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or any language code if Locale module is enabled. More on this below *
  //$node->path = array('alias' => 'your node path'); // Setting a node path
  node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.
  $node->uid = 1; // admin id
  // Let's add standard body field
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text';
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary';
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; // If field has a format, you need to define it. Here we define a default filtered_html format for a body field
  // Add images
  $image_limit = 5;
  $images = array(//images to attach to node
    '0' => 'http://cf.juggle-images.com/matte/white/280x280/drupal-logo-primary.jpg',
    '1' => 'http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/37187.png',
    '2' => 'https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/logo-128x128.jpg',
    '3' => 'http://guillermocerezo.com/sites/default/files/field/image/drupal-logo_0.jpg',
    '4' => 'http://drupalcrafters.org/sites/default/files/DrupalCraft-logo_0.png'
  );
  for ($i = 0; $i < $image_limit; $i++) {
    $file_info = system_retrieve_file($images[$i], 'public://pictures/', TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE); //storing image inside picture folder
    if ($file_info->fid) {//if fid exist then image is saved from URL.
      $node->field_multiple_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['fid'] = $file_info->fid; //assign image
    }
  }
  $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
  node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid
  drupal_set_message('article  saved !!!');
  watchdog('info', 'Article node created');
```

Comment: I try something like your code , but not work, just only one field worked.
update question with that

Comment: Wouldn't Entity Metadata Wrappers make it easier?

Comment: Both **Entity Metadata Wrappers** and **Node Object** uses the  methods `save()` and `node_save()` corresponding to save the  node. Both the functions save the node by passing the argument to `hook_node_insert()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need check the image field settings. There is set a mode - Single value, change it to unlimited for an example.

Comment: I try it , also set it to 5 limit !!!

Comment: Do you use multilanguage functionality?

Comment: I also do not see this line at the end of your code - node_save($node); :)

Comment: It is there :). but my focus on how file saved